# Desktop menu goes off screen when I try to hide it on mobile

Tags: javascript, css

I have two menus (left and right) and a search bar. When the user activates the menus, they slide from the edge of the screen as they supposed to. The menus will slide back when the search bar is clicked/tapped. This works as intended on mobile, but the right menu goes off screen when the search bar is clicked on the desktop version. 
*Note – I’ve included only two media queries and the CSS is very basic for the sake of simplicity. 
Could you please explain what am doing wrong here? 
Here’s a Jsfiddle:

```
[code]
https://jsfiddle.net/54rzcv7f/5/ 
[/code]
```

*Note - Please remember to select No wrap in body on the JavaScript tab.

Comment: They don't seem to disappear to me? I mean, besides them show and hiding based on hover. So I can't really tell how it isn't working. Is there something else that needs to be added to the code to show the effect?

Comment: It doesn't work on JSfiddle unless you select 

    No wrap-in <body>
In the JavaScript tab

Comment: ahh, I read the note but didn't see where to do that in the fiddle. Gotchya now. +1

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer:**

My advice is to use classes then. Since the right menu needs to move different distances based on screen size, adding and removing a class might work best.

**Javascript:**

```
input.addEventListener('focusin', function() {
    message.classList = "searchFocus"; 
});
input.addEventListener('focusout', function() {
    message.style="";
    message.classList = ""; 
});
```

**CSS:**

```
@media screen and (max-width:450px) and (min-width:321px){  
    .searchFocus{
       transform:translate(105%, 0%)!important;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:1920px) and (min-width:451px){ 
     .searchFocus{
         transform:translate(52%, -90%)!important;;
     }
}
```

This will still leave you with some funky stuff happening, like if you expand the menu and then resize, but that doesn't have anything to do with the focus. Using a similar method in js, just clear out the inline styling when the screen resizes past a certain size, like 451px.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: The 


    input.addEventListener('focusin', function() {
message.style.transform = "translate(100%, 0%)" }); 

Needs to be there in order for the menu to work properly on mobile devices. 

If you make the screen smaller on jsfiddle you'll notice that the mobile media query takes over. 

I hope I'm explaining this clearly because it seems very complicated to me.

Comment: @Jean-Pierre64 You're right, I wasn't taking it in enough. After some looking over, I've updated my answer